# Funcion recursiva infinita

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un ciclo recursivo infinito en Java

```
public  void infiniteLoop(Long x){

    System.out.println(""+x);
    infiniteLoop(x + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StackOverFlow st = new StackOverFlow();
    st.infiniteLoop(0L); 
}
```

En este fragmento de código que muestran un error StackOverFlow como se espera, pero si miro en la salida de la consola el error se muestra en varias líneas: 
[image: Error on multiple lines]

Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué sucede esto? ¿No debería detenerse tan pronto como se muestre el primer error de desbordamiento de pila?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en el stream de salida de la aplicación. Imagino que tu salida la imprimes en `System.out` mientras que la salida de los errores se está enviando a `System.err`. Al ser dos streams diferentes, la escritura no es secuencial. Luego, considera que cada uno de estos streams debe flushear la salida a una misma consola, y nuevamente, no es secuencial, por ello que la salida se ve extraña.

Para resolver estos inconvenientes, te recomiendo:

1. Usar un solo stream de salida. Para ello, en lugar de usar `error.printStackTrace()` (que en tu caso se usa de manera automática) podrías usar `error.printStackTrace(System.out)`.
2. Usar un sistema de logging como log4j2 o logback. Estos frameworks contienen la lógica para redireccionar la salida de manera uniforme a un solo stream de salida.